# Wrap Panel Items Separator WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this expander control with WrapPanel in it:

```
<Expander Background="Black">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <BulletDecorator>
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Image Source="../Images/Button/customiseButton_Transparent.png" Width="64" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Customize" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" />
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Expander.Header>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image  Source="Images/Button.png" />
                        <Label  Content="Phone" Foreground="Snow" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image  Source="Images/Button.png" />
                        <Label  Content="Colour" Foreground="Snow" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Expander>
```

I need a to display a white separator between the two stack panels.

I have tried adding the `<Seperator/>` tag, but it does not work

Comment: Tag:--**<Separator />** not <seperator />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Separator` is nothing more than a `Border` element really so this should work just fine:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image  Source="Images/Button.png" />
        <Label  Content="Phone" Foreground="Snow" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border Width="2" Background="Red" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image  Source="Images/Button.png" />
        <Label  Content="Colour" Foreground="Snow" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</WrapPanel>
```

Just change the `Width` and `Background` properties of the `Border` according to your requirements.

The actual `Separator` element always has a `Height` of 1 on Windows 10 unless you modify its `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this Tag:**

```
<Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
```

Comment: @dESource-It's possible